# WOT convergence in the unit ball of B(X)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

My questions is (probably) related to:

[On separable Hilbert space $H$, weak operator topology is metrizable on bounded parts of $B(H)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091508/on-separable-hilbert-space-h-weak-operator-topology-is-metrizable-on-bounded)

1. Does the theorem quoted in the above question, together with the fact that the unit ball of $B(H)$ ([or of any $B(X)$ where $X$ is reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187844/compactness-of-unit-ball-in-wot-of-bx/1187867?noredirect=1#comment2418557_1187867)) is WOT compact, imply that any *sequnce* in the unit ball of $B(H)$ has a convergent *subsequence*? In other words, is the unit ball  sequentially-WOT compact?
2. Since WOT and SOT coincide on convex sets, does this mean that any sequence in the unit ball of $B(H)$ has a SOT-convergent subsequence?
3. Do the above (if indeed true) hold when $X$ is a separable reflexive Banach space? Does the proof about metrizability of WOT on the unit ball of $B(H)$ hold in $B(X)$ as well?

Comment: Regarding #1, if $H$ is separable then the norm-closed unit ball in $B(H)$ is sequentially WOT-compact.  I'm not sure if it is true when $H$ is nonseparable, but I suspect not.

Comment: I think your assertion in 2 is wrong. The closures of every convex sets coincides in both topologies, but the topologies are DIFFERENT in general. As a counterexample, $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is a convex set and WOT and SOT do not coincide unless $H$ is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes if and only if $H$ is separable.
2. Yes if and only if $H$ is separable.
3. If I remember correctly yes. Please check [this survey paper](http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/thesis_file/14_J07-146.pdf).

Comment: Thank you again :). The survey paper is something that I should really read.

Comment: The assertion made about 2. is incorrect. Consider the unilateral shift $S.$ The sequence $S^n$ goes to $0$ in WOT but not SOT, but all are indeed contractions. More generally, when $H$ is countably infinite dimensional, the set of isometries is SOT-closed, however their WOT closure is the entire unit ball, if I recall correctly.